# Django model filter targeting JSONField where the keys contain hyphen / dash

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to apply a model filter on a JSONField BUT the keys in the JSON are UUIDs.

So when is do something like...

```
MyModel.objects.filter(data__8d8dd642-32cb-48fa-8d71-a7d6668053a7=‘bob’)
```

... I get a compile error. The hyphens in the UUID are the issue.

Any clues if there is an escape char or another behaviour to use? My database is PostgreSQL.

**Update 1 - now with added JSON**

```
{
   ‘8d8dd642-32cb-48fa-8d71-a7d6668053a7’: ’8d8dd642-32cb-48fa-8d71-a7d6668053a7’,
   ‘9a2678c4-7a49-4851-ab5d-6e7fd6d33d72’: ‘John Smith’,
   ‘9933ae39-1a27-4477-a9f4-3d1839f93fb4’: ‘Employee’
}
```

Comment: can you post a json example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's looks difficult and I'm not 100% convinced what I have will work.

You can try using the [`JsonField` contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#std:fieldlookup-jsonfield.contains) lookup. The lookup is explained more under the docs for `HStoreField` since it's shared functionality.

This would look like this:

```py
MyModel.objects.filter(data__contains={'8d8dd642-32cb-48fa-8d71-a7d6668053a7': 'bob'})
```

I think this will allow you to circumvent the fact that the lookups need to be valid Python variable names.

Comment: This did the job perfectly

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same issue where I couldn't use `__contains`, and found that you can use `**kwargs` unpacking to get it to work, which allows you to pass the filter as a string (this is also useful if you were to need a dynamic filter):

```
kwargs = {
   'data__8d8dd642-32cb-48fa-8d71-a7d6668053a7': 'bob'
}
MyModel.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to search wild card (using the example from above)

This will basically search LIKE %bob%

```
kwargs = {
   'data__8d8dd642-32cb-48fa-8d71-a7d6668053a7__icontains': 'bob'
}
MyModel.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```